# Service Worker: how to update the cache when files changed on the server?

Tags: javascript, browser-cache, service-worker

What cache strategies are you using? I read the Offline Cookbook and the simplest strategy to use is to cache static content and the left out the API calls.

This strategy seems something like this:

1. Check if the request is already in cache
2. If not add the request, response pair to cache
3. Return response

*How to update the cache if on the server side files has changed?* Currently the clients gets always the cached results.

Here is my cache strategy's code:

```js
// You will need this polyfill, at least on Chrome 41 and older.
importScripts("serviceworker-cache-polyfill.js");

var VERSION = 1;

var CACHES = {
    common: "common-cache" + VERSION
};

// an array of file locations we want to cache
var filesToCache = [
    "font-cache.html",
    "script.js",
];

var neededFiles = [
    "index.html"
];

var errorResponse = function() {

    return new Response([
            "<h2>Failed to get file</h2>",
            "<p>Could not retrive response from cache</p>"
        ].join("\n"),
        500
    );
};

var networkFetch = function(request) {

    return fetch(request).then(function(response) {

        caches.open(CACHES["common"]).then(function(cache) {

            return cache.put(request, response);
        });

    }).catch(function() {
        console.error("Network fetch failed");
        return errorResponse();
    });
}

this.addEventListener("install", function(evt) {
    evt.waitUntil(
        caches.open(CACHES["common"]).then(function(cache) {

            // Cache before
            cache.addAll(filesToCache);
            return cache.addAll(neededFiles);
        })
    );
});

this.addEventListener("activate", function(event) {

    var expectedCacheNames = Object.keys(CACHES).map(function(key) {
        return CACHES[key];
    });

    console.log("Activate the worker");

    // Active worker won"t be treated as activated until promise resolves successfully.
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.keys().then(function(cacheNames) {
            return Promise.all(
                cacheNames.map(function(cacheName) {
                    if (expectedCacheNames.indexOf() ===
                        -1) {
                        console.log(
                            "Deleting out of date cache:",
                            cacheName);

                        return caches.delete(cacheName);
                    }
                })
            );
        })
    );
});

self.addEventListener("fetch", function(event) {
    console.log("Handling fetch event for", event.request.url);

    event.respondWith(

        // Opens Cache objects
        caches.open(CACHES["common"]).then(function(cache) {
            return cache.match(event.request).then(function(
                response) {

                if (response) {
                    console.log("Found response in cache", response);

                    return response;
                } else {

                    return networkFetch(event.request);
                }
            }).catch(function(error) {

                // Handles exceptions that arise from match() or fetch().
                console.error(
                    "  Error in fetch handler:",
                    error);

                return errorResponse();
            });
        })
    );
});
```

Comment: What you mean by the server sent events ? When the page or resource gets updated send event and update cache ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may get familiar with great Jeff Posnick's solution - [sw-precache](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache).
Strategy used there is:

1. Gulp is generating Service Worker file with checksums
2. Service Worker is registered (with his own checksum)
3. If files were added/updated, the SW file changes
4. With next visit, SW checks that its checksum differs, so it registers itself once again with updated files

You may automate this flow with backend in any way you want :)

He described it much better in [this article](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2015/02/offline-first-with-sw-precache)

Comment: This seems to be good approach, the only question how the custom caching logic fits in with such method ?

Comment: You can manipulate sw-precache and introduce different caching strategies there.  
There are two strategies to consider: storing strategy and serving strategy.  
Storing strategy in this example is "on install". With some minor additional changes you could change 
`self.addEventListener('install'` to `self.addEventListener('push'`, to change to storing on push. 
You can change serving strategies (in section of `fetch` event) as well.  
Base template for sw is service-worker.tmpl in main folder.

Answer (score 2):

This is the code I use to cache. It fetches the resource and caches and serves it.

```
this.addEventListener("fetch", function(event) {
  event.respondWith(
    fetch(event.request).then(function(response) {
      return caches.open("1").then(function(cache) {
        return cache.put(event.request, response.clone()).then(function() {
          return response
        })
      })
    }).catch(function() {
      return caches.match(event.request)
    })
  )
})
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the request fetch could take some unknown time before receiving timeout. Also when you are in offline mode the cache trigger takes some time until the response is returned, from the user point of view this is not good.

Answer (score 2):

You have to change your Service Worker file.  According to [Introduction to Service Worker](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/service-worker/introduction/):

> When the user navigates to your site, the browser tries to redownload the script file that defined the service worker in the background. If there is even a byte's difference in the service worker file compared to what it currently has, it considers it 'new'.

So even if you only need to change static resources, you'll have to update your service worker file so that a new service worker is registered that updates the cache.  (You'll want to make sure to delete any previous caches as well in your `activate` handler.)  @Karol Klepacki's answer suggests a way to automate this.

Alternatively, you could implement logic in your service worker itself to periodically check cached resources for changes and update the entries appropriately.

Comment: True, as you can see the version in my worker file which should trigger "activate" event and on that the previous cached resource should be deleted. The problem is that inside the same tab on refresh the worker file is requested from server but never updated in client side until the tabs are closed.

Comment: I don't see this happening, as when I navigate to my page that has a service worker, it doesn't install it. I can tell because it was giving me all the JavaScript files and I wondered why it wasn't working until I realized what was going on. Maybe I'm wrong, but that's from what I see.